# Navegação em Android Mobile Apps

Tags: android, windows-phone

Fala galera.

Tenho um aplicativo publicado no Windows Phone no qual eu faço navegação entre páginas sem ter que me preocupar com o histórico, ou seja, se o usuário pressionar o botão Back do Windows Phone, ele automaticamente volta para a página anterior. Semelhante ao IE ou Firefox, por exemplo.

Para ficar mais claro, suponha que a página Pesquisa.xaml liste o resultado de uma pesquisa.

Neste resultado tem um link para os detalhes do registro. Quando usuario clica eu o envio para a página Detalhe.xaml?id=1

Nos detalhes da página Detalhe.xaml tem um outro link para outra referencia.
Assim, eu redireciono o usuario para a mesma página Detalhe.xaml?id=2.

E assim por diante.

Eu consigo o mesmo resultado no Android?

Lembrando que no WP, eu não me preocupo com o historico das páginas pois ele volta para a página anterior sem intervenção em código.

Abraços.

Comment: No geral não precisa se preocupar não. Mas [nesse link](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) tem bastante informacao sobre isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Android possui um mecanismo semelhante ao Windows Phone, as "páginas" são empilhadas de modo que ao pressionar o botão voltar, a Activity (página) é fechada e a anterior é exibida, se não tiver uma Activity anterior, o app fecha ou ou realiza uma ação (ir para o background, por exemplo).

Enquanto no Windows Phone você vai para outra página usando o `Navigate`, no Android, você cria uma `Intent`.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(AtualActivity.this, ProximaActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Onde `AtualActivity.this` se refere a `Activity` atual e `ProximaActivity.class` se refere a `Activity` para onde se quer ir.

Daí para voltar a Activity (página) anterior, basta chamar o `finish` ou deixa que o botão voltar cuide disso para você.

```
    finish();
```

A passagem e retorno de parâmetros é feita de modo semelhante.

Resumindo: O funcionamento da navegação é igual ao Windows Phone.

Você pode saber mais sobre:

Intents - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html?hl=pt-br

funcionamento da navegação - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html e https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html (Inglês)

Comment: Muito bom. Vlw mesmo.